# jQuery MouseEnter and MouseOut events with .toggle() reverse when the mouse is already over the element onLoad?

Tags: jquery, toggle, mouseover, reverse

I have a dropdown menu working great with the following code:

```
$('#menu ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children(".dropdown").toggle();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children(".dropdown").toggle();
});
```

This works as you would expect. The issue is that if the mouse is already `mouseenter` on the `$('#menu ul li')` when the `$(document).ready(function(){ })` is fired, the toggle works the other way round?

How can I avoid this?

EG: http://screenr.com/wbd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't you want to do `show()` on `mouseenter` and `hide()` on `mouseleave`?

Comment: show()/hide() do the same thing as toggle - same thing happens though, i think the error is with the actual events being called the wrong way round because of the mouse being over it onload :(

Comment: this was actually correct, i just realised i kept seeing if it worked and forgot to upload! :| ty :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just calling `toggle` with no arguments, your mouse event handlers can pass in explicit boolean `showOrHide` values. Pass `true` to `toggle()` in the `mouseenter` routine, and `false` in `mouseleave`. Or do as suggested by the other answer and just use `show` and `hide`.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the document without moving the mouse, no mouseover action will be toggled until you move the mouse. But i think mouseover is toggled as your mouse moves, event if it's already "over" onLoad.

What about this code ?
Anyways, i think your bug comes from mouseout not being toggled because JS only checks every x ms, and if you move too fast, it gets out of the div without calling the event.

```
$('#menu ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    // hide all other divs
    $(".dropdown").hide(0);
    // show the div we want
    $(this).children(".dropdown").show(0);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hide(0);
});
```

If you don't care about animations, doing this with CSS is always a better way then with JS.

You'll need to set it up like this :

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Menu 1
            <div class="dropdown">Sub1</div>
            <div class="dropdown">Sub2</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu 2
            <div class="dropdown">Sub1</div>
            <div class="dropdown">Sub2</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown { display: none; position: relative; }
#menu li:hover .dropdown { display: block; }
```